# Geo Location on Website

Tags: geolocation

I want to retrieve information like "city" level information of a visitor from their IP address, so that I can personalize my website according to their location. Just to let you know all, I have zero knowledge of coding (PHP, JSON, HTML, Jquery, Javascript, Ajax) etc. What I need from you experts is, whenever a visitor come to my site, it would show up their city name. For example: if you reside in "Calgary", and you visit to my website, it would show up as "Are you looking for digital marketing company in Calgary? I would be very grateful if you experts can help me? Attached is the file of an example. [personalized landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGkA2.png)

Note: I have a wordpress website.

Thank you so much in advance.